# Multiple isin queries in one statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame `df` where the head looks like:

```
id      dept       paid
97   accounts   monthly
73       shop    weekly
20  marketing    yearly
70   analysis   monthly
55   advisory   monthly
42  marketing   monthly
76  marketing    weekly
```

I am interested in looking at a subset of employees from a subset of dept and of these a subset of paid.

So for example if I wanted to return a subset of the data-frame that was `marketing` and `advisory` and of these only those paid `monthly` and `weekly`

I would return the following complete records:

```
id       dept      paid
55   advisory   monthly
42  marketing   monthly
76  marketing    weekly
```

I have tried to use two lists called deptQuery and paidQuery which look like:

```
deptQuery = ['marketing','advisory']

paidQuery = ['monthly','weekly']
```

and apply it to:

```
queryResult = df[df['dept'].isin(deptQuery) and DeptTemplate['paid'].isin(paidQuery)]
```

I also tried

```
queryResult = df[df['dept'].isin(deptQuery)] and df[df['paid'].isin(paidQuery)]
```

but I can't get it to work. What other things could I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use & for bitwise `AND` and remove `df[`:

```
queryResult = df[df['dept'].isin(deptQuery) & df['paid'].isin(paidQuery)]

print (queryResult)
   id       dept     paid
4  55   advisory  monthly
5  42  marketing  monthly
6  76  marketing   weekly
```

Another solution with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
queryResult = df.query('dept in @deptQuery & paid in @paidQuery')
```